# Количество вхождении строки в массив рекурсией

Tags: c#, рекурсия

Не могу понять как посчитать количество вхождении строки в массив с помощью рекурсией без linq c#. Есть строка string "abcdef" и массив char { 'a', 'e' }.

```
public static int GetCharsCount(string str, char[] chars)
        {            
            if (chars[0] == str[0])
            {
                return 1 + GetCharsCount(str[1..], chars);
            }
            else
            {
                return GetCharsCount(str[1..], chars);
            }

            return GetCharsCount(str, chars);
```

Comment: Для сверки результата `int count = new string(chars).Split(str).Length - 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Условие выхода из рекурсии нужно указывать до основной части.

```
public static int GetCharsCount(
    string str, char[] chars,
    int charsIndex = 0  // значение по умолчанию для внешних вызовов
)
{
    if (charsIndex == chars.Length)
    {
        charsIndex = 0;
        str = str[1..];
    }

    if (str == String.Empty) // условие выхода
        return 0;

    return (chars[charsIndex] == str[0] 
            ? 1
            : 0) 
        + GetCharsCount(str, chars, charsIndex + 1);
}
```

Comment: Два бокала вина этому джентльмену!

Comment: @МарекВуицик Просто поставьте галку возле ответа - это лучший вариант для вас как для топикстартера.